# Microsoft LUIS - cannot train ANY model

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I can't seem to find anything on any of the Azure service pages, and I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same problems, or if I'm cursed.

On ANY LUIS app that I try and train, I get an error: "App training failed: None: Retrain" (see screenshot). The "None" is the name of the intent, which varies depending on which app I'm trying.

I've tried multiple Azure logins/accounts/subscriptions, I've tried adding an utterance to an existing app that works, I've tried creating a very basic new app with 2 intents with a few utterances - all give me the same error. I am in Central/West US regions.

All of the Azure service pages say everything's just fine. I'm at a bit of a loss...

[Screenshot of LUIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjA2S.png)

Comment: Hi Ben. We're currently tracking this. Can you let me know if this is still broken for you as of this morning, and if it is, please edit your question with a snippet of your LUIS model so we can see if there is something in common with the other people having the same issue?

Comment: Hello, it's working now! When I was trying it out, I tested it with multiple different models. The most basic one was just a simple, brand new bot, with no entities or anything, and just a single intent with a few utterances, and it still failed with the same error. All OK now though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just you! LUIS training seems to be down at the moment. I've contacted their twitter support but it may just be a case of waiting. [Luis training service seems to be completely down/failing and the error message resulting for that fact is completely unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814412/luis-training-service-seems-to-be-completely-down-failing-and-the-error-message) is another Stack Overflow user with this issue.

Update: The issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate knowing it's not just me going crazy. :-)