# Luis training service seems to be completely down/failing and the error message resulting for that fact is completely unhelpful

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

After a bout of repeated training and deleting patterns and intense scrutiny of what might be happening to our LUIS models, it seems as though Luis is completely down.

Here is what is repeatedly happening when trying to train a LUIS model.
[image: luis training error message]

The reason why I was questioning the error being something on our part is because of this previous [stackoverflow QA on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57482652/luis-app-fails-to-train-app-training-failed-l-general-retrain) [Also, this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d83a2e58-85e3-4eec-85b3-f0e3a4a20d2f/luis-app-fails-to-train-app-training-failed-lgeneral-retrain?forum=LUIS). These previous reported instances of training failures do not address this issue but they seem closely related.

However, the reality is I have went and made new models and the same effect and I have made new models on a personal account and it still is holding the same affect of LUIS not training models and is seemingly just down as far as training goes.

My ask is that if the LUIS training service is down, which that is a very understandable possibility, can there be a clear error message to this fact rather than something that can be misconstrued as user input or modeling error.

Comment: Hi Christian. We're currently tracking this. Can you let me  know if this is still broken for you as of this morning, and if it is, please edit your question with a snippet of your LUIS model so we can see if there is something in common with the other people having the same issue?

Comment: seems to be all working now